# Is there any difference between empty derived class and using?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typedef, using

I'm writing a library whose functionalities are provided in a C-compatible header like the following:

```
// File: bar.h

typedef struct bar_context_t bar_context_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  bar_context_t* bar_create();
  void bar_destroy(bar_context_t*);

  int bar_do_stuff(bar_context_t*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and implemented in C++:

```
// File: bar.cpp

namespace bar {
  class Context {
    private:
      // ...
    public:
      int do_stuff();
  };
}
```

The problem is how to connect `bar::Context` to `bar_context_t` so I can implement the extern C functions.

I can think of two options:

Option A: Using

```
using bar_context_t = bar::Context;
```

Option B: Empty Derived Class

```
struct bar_context_t : public bar::Context {};
```

Which option is better? Or is there a better third option?

Comment: With `typedef struct bar_context_t bar_context_t;` you have already told the compiler that `bar_context_t` is a `struct`, so you can't really be `using` the class (as that would attempt to "override" the type-alias you have created with `typedef`).

Comment: You might be overthinking it - you can simply `reinterpret_cast` and it's fine as long as you cast back to bar::Context* before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is necessary (and I don't even think your first variant works; `using` is just C++ syntax sugar, and does not introduce a type).

You just declare `bar_context_t` to be a pointer to `bar::Context`; that's it. In C, you declare it to be a `void*`, since C has no type safety anyways.¹

---

¹strictly speaking, C has type safety, between the two types "function pointer" and "not a function pointer".